# Javascript scroll to div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've searched on google the solution to my problem, and I can't understand why the code I've written work for everyone, but not for me.

I've written this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollTo() {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#div_id').offset().top }, 'slow');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .uno {
            height: 1000px;
            background: #808080;
        }
        .due {
            margin-top: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #ff00ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="uno" onclick="scrollTo()"> 
        Clicca
    </div>
    <div class="due" id="div_id"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you included jquery library

Comment: Why not check console before posting on SO? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollTo() {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#div_id').offset().top }, 'slow');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .uno {
            height: 1000px;
            background: #808080;
        }
        .due {
            margin-top: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #ff00ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="uno" onclick="scrollTo()"> 
        Clicca
        </div>
        <div class="due" id="div_id"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this:

Comment: Please try this is working after including jquery library in above code

Comment: Yes, I'm a complete idiot... i tryed to make work a jquery script without include jquery. omg...

Comment: @Daniele hahahha, Some time occurs this

Comment: @DanieleNekoLuciani: If the suggested solution solves your issue, accept this as answer. This may help others as well.

Comment: Ofcourse, but I've to w8 some minutes. It's for this I'm here still.

Comment: This is not Javascript, can you also update how to do this in javascript only, I am working on chrome extension.

Answer (score 4):

Change your script to:

```
$('.uno').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#div_id").offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

and remove `onclick` from the first div.

A demo is in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2VaV/3/).

Answer (score 3):

see my jsfiddle:

you should add jquery to your codes, and this is my way:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/e6zFH/)

and in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/e6zFH/2/) if you click on each div you will scroll to other div
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/e6zFH/2/)

**Javascript**

```
$("#firstDiv").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#div_id').offset().top }, 'slow');

 })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="uno" id="firstDiv"> 
    Clicca
</div>
<div class="due" id="div_id"></div>
```